# OData with ABP only returns 404 for entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm developing a .NET Core 2.2 web app, using ABP and OData, and I've followed [this guide](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration). After setting everything up, I can query `http://localhost:21021/odata` and get the following result:

> {"result":{"entitySets":[{"url":"Empresas","name":"Empresas","title":null,"typeAnnotation":null},{"url":"Users","name":"Users","title":null,"typeAnnotation":null}],"singletons":[],"functionImports":[],"typeAnnotation":null},"targetUrl":null,"success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"__abp":true}

But anything I try with my entities, like hitting `http://localhost:21021/odata/Empresas`, just results in a 404.

What could be the problem?

Startup.cs

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // MVC
        services.AddMvc(
            options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName))
        );

        services.AddOData();

        // Workaround: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1177
        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
            {
                outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
            }
            foreach (var inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
            {
                inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
            }
        });

        IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
        AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);
        // ... SignalR, CORS, Swagger, etc ...

        return services.AddAbp<EcfWebHostModule>(
            // Configure Log4Net logging
            options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
            )
        );

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

        // ... UseCors, UseStaticFiles, UseAuthentication, UseAbpRequestLocalization, UseSignalR ...

        app.UseOData(builder =>
        {
            builder.EntitySet<EmpresaEntity>("Empresas").EntityType.Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
            builder.EntitySet<User>("Users").EntityType.Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
        });

        app.UseUnitOfWork(options =>
        {
            options.Filter = httpContext =>
            {
                return httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/odata");
            };
        });

        // ... Swagger ...

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapODataServiceRoute(app);

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "defaultWithArea",
                template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

EmpresaController.cs

```
public class EmpresaController : AbpODataEntityController<EmpresaEntity>, ITransientDependency
{
    public EmpresaController(IRepository<EmpresaEntity> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {

    }
}
```

EmpresaEntity.cs

```
public sealed class EmpresaEntity : FullAuditedEntity
{
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you get the metadata? `http://localhost:21021/odata/$metadata`

Comment: Yes, I can. I also implemented a filter to not wrap the responses. So, I can get a XML file with all my entities, as expected.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a routing problem somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it.

Just had to change the name of the controller to match the string passed as parameter in the startup class. It wasn't clear from the documentation that was how it worked.

```
builder.EntitySet<EmpresaEntity>("Empresas").EntityType.Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
```

and

```
EmpresasController
```